# ConfigurationProperties load depends on value

Tags: java, spring

Here's my yaml file, and I want to load my properties depends on activation value.

```
emp:
 activate: a
 a: 
  param1: value1
  param2: value2
 b:
  param1: value1
  param2: value2
```

I want to do if activate value is 'a' then load 'a'.

on my source code, AppConfig

```
@Getter @Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppConfig {
 @NestedConfigurationProperty
 private final EmpConfig empConfig;
}
```

my EmpConfig

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "emp")
public class EmpConfig {
private String activate;
private Emp a;
private Emp b;

public Emp getEmpConfig(){
    if(activate.equals("a"))
        return a;
    return b;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public static class Emp {
    private String param1;
    private String param2;
}
}
```

But those code got bean creation error. Is there any nice method to resolve this problem?

Comment: Show the error you get.

Comment: AppConfig required a bean of type 'EmpConfig$Emp' that could not be found.